# How to install Python or R in an apptainer?

Tags: python, docker, apptainer

I am new to docker and using apptainer for that.

the def file is: **`firstApp.def`**:

```
`Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:22.04

%environment
    export LC_ALL=C
`
```

then I built it as follows and I want it to be writable (I hope I am not so naive), so I can install some packages later:

```
`apptainer build --sandbox --fakeroot firstApp.sif firstApp.def
`
```

now I do not know how to install Python3 (preferably, 3.8 or later).

I tried to add the following command lines to the def file:

```
`%post
   apt-get -y install update
   apt-get -y install python3.8 `
```

it raises these errors as well even without "`apt-get -y install python3.8`":

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update
FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me
`%post`

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat python3.8`